# How to copy file from a network using Python

Tags: python, network-shares

I want to use Python to copy a zip file (test.zip) from shared network (\svr\shared) to my local computer C:\ drive. Also, my windows account already has access to the network.

One more thing, how can I get the content of a network shared folder? Let's say, I need all the file names located at \svr\shared.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use something like FileZilla with a GUI? Unless you're a server administrator managing/transferring a lot of files, something like FileZilla has all the features you want and would be the path of least resistance

Comment: There's no difference between accessing files on a network and accessing files on your local disk.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
from shutil import copyfile
src = r'\svr\shared\test.zip'
dst = r'C:\test.zip'
copyfile(src, dst)
```

Comment: how about raw strings like `r'C:\test.zip'` to avoid surprises such as that tab in the file name?